# Trying to find gaps between times in two separate columns and separate rows

Tags: t-sql

This is a sample of point of sale data from a restaurant: all times in one day for one person that a check was open and closed. I'm trying to find the gaps between when a person closed a check and opened another (basically the amount of time they had no checks open each day). I was using the Lead function but that didn't account for the situations where a check was opened after others but closed earlier than the others (chk_num 499 is a good example). I can tell by checking this data manually that there were no checks open from 14:27:35 to 14:29:14.000 and from 16:01:12.000 to 16:59:22.000, but I can't figure out how to do it automatically across the larger dataset.

I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 11.0.2100.60 on SQL Server 2012 to write this query.

Sorry for the formatting below. I can't find a good explanation of how to insert a simple table.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>chk_num</th><th>employee</th><th>chkstarttm</th><th>chkendtm</th></tr><tr><td>473</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 12:26:44.000</td><td>2013-05-15 13:21:58.000</td></tr><tr><td>480</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 12:38:17.000</td><td>2013-05-15 13:49:07.000</td></tr><tr><td>483</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 12:45:54.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:27:35.000</td></tr><tr><td>484</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 12:46:19.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:09:52.000</td></tr><tr><td>495</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 13:19:58.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:10:02.000</td></tr><tr><td>499</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 13:30:38.000</td><td>2013-05-15 13:56:58.000</td></tr><tr><td>503</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 13:40:01.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:11:47.000</td></tr><tr><td>515</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:29:14.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:40:25.000</td></tr><tr><td>517</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:32:32.000</td><td>2013-05-15 16:01:12.000</td></tr><tr><td>522</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:34:57.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:41:31.000</td></tr><tr><td>521</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:34:57.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:03:02.000</td></tr><tr><td>523</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:34:57.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:02:32.000</td></tr><tr><td>519</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:34:57.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:40:56.000</td></tr><tr><td>520</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 14:34:57.000</td><td>2013-05-15 14:41:53.000</td></tr><tr><td>525</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 15:00:17.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:27:55.000</td></tr><tr><td>535</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 15:27:13.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:43:48.000</td></tr><tr><td>536</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 15:29:54.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:30:56.000</td></tr><tr><td>537</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 15:41:06.000</td><td>2013-05-15 15:41:42.000</td></tr><tr><td>548</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 16:59:22.000</td><td>2013-05-15 18:04:47.000</td></tr><tr><td>551</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 17:04:35.000</td><td>2013-05-15 18:29:35.000</td></tr><tr><td>564</td><td>20106</td><td>2013-05-15 18:03:22.000</td><td>2013-05-15 19:35:51.000</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution I believe you could use:

```
    --Generated Output        
    StartRange                      EndRange
    2013-05-15 14:27:35.000         2013-05-15 14:29:14.000
    2013-05-15 16:01:12.000         2013-05-15 16:59:22.000

    DECLARE @CheckData AS TABLE
    (
        CheckNum INT,
        EmployeeNum INT,
        StartDate DATETIME,
        EndDate DATETIME
    )

    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('473', '20106', '2013-05-15 12:26:44.000', '2013-05-15 13:21:58.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('480', '20106', '2013-05-15 12:38:17.000', '2013-05-15 13:49:07.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('483', '20106', '2013-05-15 12:45:54.000', '2013-05-15 14:27:35.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('484', '20106', '2013-05-15 12:46:19.000', '2013-05-15 14:09:52.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('495', '20106', '2013-05-15 13:19:58.000', '2013-05-15 14:10:02.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('499', '20106', '2013-05-15 13:30:38.000', '2013-05-15 13:56:58.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('503', '20106', '2013-05-15 13:40:01.000', '2013-05-15 14:11:47.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('515', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:29:14.000', '2013-05-15 14:40:25.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('517', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:32:32.000', '2013-05-15 16:01:12.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('522', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:34:57.000', '2013-05-15 14:41:31.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('521', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:34:57.000', '2013-05-15 15:03:02.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('523', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:34:57.000', '2013-05-15 15:02:32.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('519', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:34:57.000', '2013-05-15 14:40:56.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('520', '20106', '2013-05-15 14:34:57.000', '2013-05-15 14:41:53.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('525', '20106', '2013-05-15 15:00:17.000', '2013-05-15 15:27:55.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('535', '20106', '2013-05-15 15:27:13.000', '2013-05-15 15:43:48.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('536', '20106', '2013-05-15 15:29:54.000', '2013-05-15 15:30:56.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('537', '20106', '2013-05-15 15:41:06.000', '2013-05-15 15:41:42.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('548', '20106', '2013-05-15 16:59:22.000', '2013-05-15 18:04:47.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('551', '20106', '2013-05-15 17:04:35.000', '2013-05-15 18:29:35.000') 
    INSERT INTO @CheckData VALUES ('564', '20106', '2013-05-15 18:03:22.000', '2013-05-15 19:35:51.000') 

    SELECT *
    FROM
        (
            SELECT MAX(enddate) OVER(ORDER BY startdate) StartRange,
             lead(startdate) OVER(ORDER BY startdate) EndRange
            FROM @Checkdata
        ) AS c
    WHERE c.StartRange < c.EndRange
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be what I needed.